# Can anyone help me find the kinematic solution of a robot arm?

Tags: matlab, solidworks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I draw a robot arm in Solidworks, but not so sure about how to find out the DOF, forward and backward kinematics..... Can anyone help me /___?

https://www.flickr.com/photos/22576989@N04/16355503864/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206246/can-anyone-help-me-find-the-kinematic-solution-of-a-robot-arm?/) by [s1155031008](https://answers.ros.org/users/22022/s1155031008/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to create a [URDF](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf) and specify the parameters of your robot through that file. Once you do that, you can [export your SW parts to the URDF](http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter).

---

Originally posted by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) with karma: 593 on 2015-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0